# How can I get an HTML form to align to the right of a previous form?

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML forms. I want the second one to align to the right of the first one (not below it).

I fiddled (no pun intended) with "display: inline-block;"

The pertinent CSS:

```
.form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The pertinent HTML:

```
<form>
    <label class="firstblocklabel">Traveler's name:</label>
    <input class="firstblockinput" type="text" id="travelername" title="Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial" />
    </br>
    . . .
</form>

<form>
    <label>Trip Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tripnumber" title="If Applicable" />
    </br>  
</form>
```

The whole shebang can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/karpxwn2/5/).

Is the solution to place the two forms in a table, or is there a more elegant element solution?

Comment: you are targeting an element with the class of 'form' and you don't have any on your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `inline-block` a width must be defined as inline just say to browser that you don't want to jump to the next line.

a best practice is to have a container then for each element you want side-by-side you put a percent value corresponding to 100% divided by the number of columns. Example : 100% / 2 columns make columns of 50% each; 100% / 4 columns would make 25% each; etc.

make sure that you columns have padding/margin/border to 0 as it wouldn't work otherwise and if you need padding, place it in a child element inside the column element.

everythings is better with examples so here it is :

```css
input{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -2px;
}

form{
  /* we can add geometry to our form */
  border: 4px solid #ddd;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container{
  padding: 0;
}

.col{
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}

.col:hover{
  /* just to see it */
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0px red;
  
}

.col-half{
  width: 50%;
}
.col-quater{
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>example 1</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col-half">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <h3>Some form...</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </form>
    </div><div class="col col-half">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <h3>Another form...</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>example 2</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col-half">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <h3>1/2 form...</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </form>
    </div><div class="col col-quater">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <h3>1/4 form...</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </form>
    </div><div class="col col-quater">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <h3>Another 1/4 form...</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Bonus:

Usually, frameworks works on a grid system : If we take bootstrap as an example, they work on a 12 col grid. meaning that if you use the class `col-6` `6` being half of `12` you get 50% width, and there goes for all other sizes. 12 is very flexible, the more cols your grid have, the more possibility it have (and the more css you must write) in my example, I made a gird of 4. we could rename `col-half` for `col-2` and `col-quater` for `col-1` so that makes sense as a grid system

Comment: One last thing ;) A common trouble people come across is forgetting to remove white spaces between elements. I did `</div><div class="col col-quater">` on purpose so we don't have space between them. This is why there is also the float technique but can get very messy as you build up a bigger stylesheet and when you want to maintain it. Both answer are suitable depending your needs

Answer (score 2):

Use float...

```
form {
    float: left
}
```

Stick a `float:right` on the 2nd form to align it to the right side.

Comment: Actually, there will be a third one, so I will float right that one.

Comment: To save on having to having to define separate css with different floats, a left float on all of them will just float alongside each other and just use the same CSS styling to make them all look nice and consistent (i.e. margin/padding)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 form {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:top; // Added
    }
```

Comment: The `.form` should change to `form` as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you accidently used a `.form` class instead of using `form` for your selector.

Second, adding `vertical-align: top` to your form selector will allow it to align to the right of your first form as long as there is space.

```
form {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

However, if your view is too narrow it will slide underneath anyways.

Comment: Interesting; both "float: right" and this more verbose way work. I wonder which is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

You added a . (.form) means class selection but your html tag doesn't contain a class

So remove the . should make your form work correctly.

```
form {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using Bootstrap and their helper classes to accomplish this?  Especially if you already have Bootstrap loaded?  Could use their grid to accomplish a 2 column layout.